# not applied css when switching the dynamic content

Tags: php, html, css

on my [website](http://www.rocketleague-base.com/) when the content switches to impressum once you click on it, it doesnt apply my css style, cant seem to find the problem. HTML-code: seen with ctrl + u on website!

```
<?php include ("$website_pages/navbar.html");?>
<div id="content">
    <?php 
    if ($_GET ['page'] == "impressum1") {
        include ("$website_pages/impressum1.html");
    } else {
        include ("$website_pages/home.html");
    }
    ?>
    <div id="impressum">
        <a href="index.php/?page=impressum1">Impressum</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML code as part of the question too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to remove the / in your link. You have relative paths that were affected by the /

```
http://quersteil.eu/index.php?page=impressum1
```

Comment: thanks, worked. can you explain what the relative path exactly means? is it redirecting to the folder index.php that doesnt exist?

Comment: You have this relative link <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">. If you have a / after index.php the path for styles.css is relative to the last /. http://quersteil.eu/index.php/style.css (this file didn't exist) If you remove the last / the path is http://quersteil.eu/style.css (exists) So you had broken paths for your css and images (sorry for my english level)

Answer (score 0):

Your css is not beeing loaded. You need to change your link to:

`<link href="/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: i just didnt include that part in my code, sry other answer worked